# Insert Json data in MySQL json column format using Python

Tags: python, mysql, json, mysql-python

I'm trying to insert Json data that I've scraped with Python into a json column format into a MySQL table

Here is the table that I created:

```
CREATE TABLE Json (
 id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 rawJson JSON NOT NULL,
 dateCreated TIMESTAMP
)
```

Here is the Python code that trying to insert the Json data

```
import json
import string
import MySQLdb
import urllib2
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host= "localhost",
    user="####",
    passwd="####",
    db="####")
x = conn.cursor()

url = 'http://example.com/file.json'
data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))

try:
    x.execute("""INSERT INTO `Json`(`rawJson`, `dateCreated`) VALUES (%s, UTC_TIMESTAMP())""", (data))
    conn.commit()
except: 
    conn.rollback()
    print "FAIL"
```

I'm able to manually take the json data and insert it into the table, but it fails at the execute step

Comment: You should add simple `raise` to the `except` block in order to see the error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

**[json.load](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)** *Deserialize fp (a .read()-supporting file-like object containing a JSON document) to a **Python object***. That means `data` is Python Object, but your are expecting it as `%s` (string). And that's the reason, it is failing.

So, I'm assuming below gives you expected JSON

```
urllib2.urlopen(url)
```

Then, you need to change

```
data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))
```

to

```
data = urllib2.urlopen(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
     import json
     # data = {'my':'name','is':'taylor swift'}
     dumped_datas = json.dumps(data)
     x.execute("""INSERT INTO `Json`(`rawJson`) VALUES (%s)""", (data))
```

This will let allow you to put your json/dict in Mysql as Json type object
json.dumps will turn you dict/json into a string, mysql will take it as a json